# Multiple push notifications is redirecting to the same page using Android Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I am using Google Cloud Messaging to send push notifications in android application.I have an activity page in which i maintained the tab bar layouts.For example,If I received five notifications means and from the five, i have clicked the fourth one, it will go to the first received notification page instead of fourth received notification page.It will redirect to the same page for all notifications.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
   private int notificationIdOne = 111;
   private int notificationIdTwo = 112;
   private int numMessagesOne = 0;


   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Button notOneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationOne);
      notOneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
            displayNotificationOne();
            displayNotificationTwo();
         }
      }); 
   }

   protected void displayNotificationOne() {

      // Invoking the default notification service
      NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);  

      mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Message with explicit intent");
      mBuilder.setContentText("New message from javacodegeeks received");
      mBuilder.setTicker("Explicit: New Message Received!");
      mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
     mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
      // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives 
      mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesOne);

      // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app 
      Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationOne.class);
      resultIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationIdOne);
      resultIntent.putExtra("notificationtext", "One");

      //This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of the app to Home page
      TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
      // Adds the back stack for the Intent
      stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationOne.class);

      // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
      stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
      PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
         stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT //can only be used once
         );
      // start the activity when the user clicks the notification text
      mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

      myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

      // pass the Notification object to the system 
      myNotificationManager.notify(notificationIdOne, mBuilder.build());
   }

   protected void displayNotificationTwo() {

       // Invoking the default notification service
          NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);  

          mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Message with 222");
          mBuilder.setContentText("Message from 222");
          mBuilder.setTicker("2222 New Message Received!");
          mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
          mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
          // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives 
          mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesOne);

          // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app 
          Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationOne.class);
          resultIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationIdTwo);
          resultIntent.putExtra("notificationtext", "two");

          //This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of the app to Home page
          TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
          // Adds the back stack for the Intent
          stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationOne.class);

          // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
          stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
          PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
             stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT //can only be used once
             );
          // start the activity when the user clicks the notification text
          mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

          myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

          // pass the Notification object to the system 
          myNotificationManager.notify(notificationIdTwo, mBuilder.build()); 

   }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you attach a onClick listener with a string var that stores the message data received to your notifications on the tabview and when you click on them, make a Toast message using the stored string. If this succeeds, then you can create an activity with textviews that can be changed every time user clicks on each different notification and update its message accordingly. Otherwise, onClick listener is probably always listening for the first notification alone.

Comment: It keeps redirecting to the same content within an activity? Also, is `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` the flag that you need?